# WordPress and Drupal questions migrated here that are better suited at their SE-specific site

Tags: discussion

Periodically we get Drupal and WordPress questions here that are clearly better suited at the Drupal and WordPress SE sites respectively. It obvious that they are sent here because Webmasters is one of the options when choosing to mark a question as off topic, and Drupal and WordPress are not available at all.

Should we forward those migrated questions on to the appropriate site? I am under the impression that double migrations is frowned upon.

If not, is there are way to allow StackOverflow and other sites to choose the Drupal and WordPress SE sites when migrating those questions?

I know there is overlap between sites but if someone has a question about coding for Drupal or WordPress they are going to get more and probably better responses from those communities.

Comment: It would be good if we could get Drupal and Wordpress on that list of related sites. I wasn't even aware we had a Drupal site in the family.

Comment: FYI drupal.se is [out of beta](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/506/new-design-launched) as of about a week ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double migrations aren't possible except by diamond mods.

We can't add Drupal anywhere because it is still in beta; beyond that, we only allow 4 close targets (the fifth is always meta) and you'd have to make a case that this happens often enough to kick another site off the Stack Overflow blessed closed targets list.

We have considered a much more complex "let the receiving site decide if they want the question" scheme but that is many months away, if at all.

I'd be curious how often this is actually happening before taking action.

Comment: I wouldn't say it happens "a lot". Just often enough for me to raise the issue here. What might be an alternative solution would be when a site is voted for migration it is queued and diamond mods can decide where it goes?

Comment: @john I don't want to show people a list of 40+ options for migration; that is a non-starter

Comment: @john one thing that IS an option is to unlock the migration route between here and Wordpress. I'll do that now. (Drupal is still in beta)

Comment: Drupal Answers is not a beta site anymore, now.

Comment: @kia fine; how many drupal migrations are we seeing to there?